# Is there a difference between $(2\,\,4) \circ (1\,\,3)$ and $(2\,\,4)(1\,\,3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, notation

Is there a difference between $(2\,\,4) \circ (1\,\,3)$ and $(2\,\,4)(1\,\,3)$?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $(24)(13)$ refers to the permutation
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
in [two-line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Two-line_notation),
whereas $(24)$ and $(13)$ are the permutations
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
1 & 4 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ 
\text{ and } \ \ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
respectively. When we compose $(24)$ with $(13)$ to get $(24)\circ (13)$ we mean
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \  \ \text{which simplifies to } \ \ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence the composition has the same two-line expression as $(24)(13)$ so $(24)\circ(13) = (24)(13)$.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is the result of $(2\, 4)$ on the left side and $(1\, 3)$ on the right side of the binary operation $\circ$, commonly understood to mean the composition of the two permutations as functions (unless stated otherwise); the second is the concatenation of $(2\, 4)$ and $(1\, 3)$ and is commonly understood to mean the same thing (when the context is clear).

Answer (score 1):

$(2\,\,4)(1\,\,3)$ is a misuse of the multiplication record instead of composing. We have the same example in matrix multiplication. In fact, it is not about multiplication of matrices, but about composing a matrix. So $A B$ is actualy a matrix composition, not a matrix multiplication.

Comment: Calling every use of concatenation (i.e. “multiplication notation”) for anything other than multiplication a misuse is probably not helpful. The notation is too useful and there are many things similar enough to multiplication that restricting yourself to multiplication of numbers is simply infeasible. It’s better to get used to it because others will stop using it.

Comment: Adding to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051593/is-there-a-difference-between-2-4-circ-1-3-and-2-41-3/3051603#comment6291227_3051601), most of semigroup theory is done using concatenation as the binary operation. It'd be unsightly and impractical otherwise.